# R and DT: Show filter option on specific columns

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I want to use [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) to display some data and allow filtering on only some of the columns. This code:

```
df <- data.frame(c("john","susy"), c("a", "b"))
names(df) <- c("name", "grade")
DT::datatable(df, filter = 'top')
```

Creates a table with filtering options over each column:

[image]

Now say I only want to have the filter box visible for the "name" column. How do I do that? I thought I could use filter like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c("john","susy"), c("a", "b"))
names(df) <- c("name", "grade")
DT::datatable(df, filter = c('none', 'top'))
```

To only enable it on the second column, but it doesn't work (it only takes a single character argument). Any ideas? Note that I want the top right search box to search on all fields, but I only want the column-specific box over the second column.

Comment: This Link may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797072/r-datatable-hide-search-box-for-individual-columns

Comment: Did you find an answer to this challenge? If so, could you share it with us?

Comment: I never found an answer to this, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I dont belive you can modify the aspect of the filter option, but you can disable its function by setting `searchable = FALSE` for the specific columns you don't want to be filtered on.

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
DT::datatable(
  df, filter = 'top',
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(targets = 1, searchable = FALSE))
  )
)
```