# How to Implement DataTables Option in Shiny R syntax?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt, datatables-1.10

I am trying to add an option for DataTable in Shiny using some of the expanded options that are found in DataTables.

I want to implement the opetion SearchBuilder.columns so that the search box can only search in the "id" column
https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchBuilder.columns

How does one implement this option into R Shiny?  What is the syntax?

The code below did not work.

```
output$table_pred <- DT::renderDataTable(df, options = list(pageLength =5), searchBuilder.columns = df$id)
```

Here is the full code:

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

setwd("c:/Desktop/datasets/")

df <- read.csv("prediction_data.csv")

df2 <- read.csv("test_data.csv")



ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           dataTableOutput('table_pred')
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           dataTableOutput('table_test')
    )
  )
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #rendering the datatable for rediction data

  output$table_pred <- DT::renderDataTable(df, options = list(pageLength =5), searchBuilder.columns = df$id)
  
  output$table_test <- DT::renderDataTable(df2,options = list(pageLength =10))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Awesome extension!

[image]

It is not available in the 'DT' package. Here is how you can use it.

Firstly, download [the JavaScript file and the CSS file](https://datatables.net/download/release#SearchBuilder).

Then, here is the R code:

```r
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  id = c("sub0", "sub0", "sub1", "sub1", "sub2")
)

dtable <- datatable(
  dat,
  options = list(
    dom = "Qlfrtip",
    searchBuilder = list(
      columns = list(2) # 2 is the index of the 'id' column
    )
  )
)

path_to_searchBuilder <- # path to the folder containing the two searchBuilder files
  normalizePath("~/Work/R/DT/searchBuilder/")

dep <- htmlDependency(
  name = "searchBuilder",
  version = "1.0.0", 
  src = path_to_searchBuilder,
  script = "dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js",
  stylesheet = "searchBuilder.dataTables.min.css",
  all_files = FALSE
)

dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))

dtable
```

Comment: That is really cool. I will try to implement this into my shiny app. Thank you for clearing up the options that DataTable has

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just adding since I came across this in my own research and also looked to searchBuilder as a solution. Following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797072/r-datatable-hide-search-box-for-individual-columns), I made only one column available for searching, which made it so that the global search functionality was also limited to just that one column. It does leave a search bar above that column, but for my use case this was the most direct and simplest solution I found without having to install anything new.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).